# Why won't switch display cout command?

Tags: c++

I am currently doing a project for class and ran into a little bug. I am trying to loop my switch statement back to the top if a certain char is not selected. I have managed to do that at the dispense that now my cout statement inside the switch will not output.

```cpp
cout << "Do you wish to enter the radius of the circle (Y/N):";
cin >> userSecChoice;
while(userSecChoice != 'y' && userSecChoice != 'Y' && userSecChoice != 'n' && userSecChoice != 'N'){
    switch(userSecChoice){
        case 'Y':
        case 'y':
            cout << "Y";
            break;
        case 'n':
        case 'N':
            cout << "Default value radius = 1.0 assumed!";
            break;
        default:
            cout << "try again:";
            cin >> userSecChoice;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're using a `switch`, that surrounding `while` should not have to test the same thing the `switch` is testing. Just set a condition that causes the `while` to stop, like `while (!done)`. Even better: Have a function that asks a yes/no question and loops for you if necessary.

Comment: Your `while` condition seems to be wrong. At least, if the condition is true, you'll never hit any of your switch cases.

Comment: From a usability perspective consider asking instead "Enter radius (default 1.0):" and taking string input you can convert, or just treating 0.0 as a "use default".

Comment: Your `switch` is useless, since it is checking for values that the `while` is ignoring. The loop is effectively `while (userSecChoice != 'y' && userSecChoice != 'Y' && userSecChoice != 'n' && userSecChoice != 'N'){ cout << "try again:"; cin >> userSecChoice; }`

Answer (score 1):

Use a do-while instead to make sure that the switch is executed at least once.

```
cout << "Do you wish to enter the radius of the circle (Y/N):";
do{
    cin >> userSecChoice;
    switch(userSecChoice){
        case 'Y':
        case 'y':
            cout << "Y";
            break;
        case 'n':
        case 'N':
            cout << "Default value radius = 1.0 assumed!";
            break;
        default:
            cout << "try again:";
            break;
    }
} while(userSecChoice != 'y' && userSecChoice != 'Y' && userSecChoice != 'n' && userSecChoice != 'N');
```